# How to automate Visual Studio from external 64-bit process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, 64-bit

I want to automate Visual Studio from an external C# program. I get the DTE object for a given processId as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2011/08/10/how-to-get-dte-from-visual-studio-process-id/). Then I get a ServiceProvider and IVsActivityLog from the DTE object as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166401.aspx).

All works fine as `x86`, but I'm running into trouble as soon as I build as `x64` (For `Any CPU` it works if and only if it runs as part of a 32-bit process). Setting the text in the status bar works, but I get an exception in the cast to `IVsActivityLog`:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsActivityLog'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{76AF73F9-A322-42B0-A515-D4D7553508FE}' failed due to the following error: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

This a simplified example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int processID = 42;  // well... replace by the correct PID
        _DTE dte = GetDTE(processID);
        dte.StatusBar.Text = $"Hello World!";

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte.DTE);
        var log = (IVsActivityLog)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsActivityLog));
        log.LogEntry((uint)__ACTIVITYLOG_ENTRYTYPE.ALE_WARNING, typeof(Program).ToString(), "Test");
    }

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);

    public static _DTE GetDTE(int processId)
    {
        IntPtr numFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
        IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
        IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator;
        IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];

        GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);
        runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);
        monikerEnumerator.Reset();

        while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, numFetched) == 0)
        {
            IBindCtx ctx;
            CreateBindCtx(0, out ctx);

            string runningObjectName;
            monikers[0].GetDisplayName(ctx, null, out runningObjectName);

            object runningObjectVal;
            runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out runningObjectVal);

            if (runningObjectVal is _DTE && runningObjectName.StartsWith("!VisualStudio"))
            {
                int currentProcessId = int.Parse(runningObjectName.Split(':')[1]);

                if (currentProcessId == processId)
                {
                    return (_DTE)runningObjectVal;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Technically this is possible.  Practically it is not, the VS installer writes a *ton* of registry keys.  They are only visible to a 32-bit process.

Comment: Hmm :-/  Thank you, Hans